# Introspection of win32com module / pythoncom module

Tags: python

what is the best way to see what all functions that can be performed using pythoncom module?
Specifically, i was working with the win32com module to operate upon excel files. I was not able to find introspection for it as we do for the rest of the modules.
Can anyone please suggest how can i retrieve this information?

Answer (score 5):

run the make.py file in \lib\site-packages\win32com\client.

When you run it, a dialog comes up showing installed COM objects... choose the one for the Excel Ojbect library and you'll get something like this:

```
c:\Python26\Lib\site-packages\win32com\client>makepy.py
Generating to C:\Python26\lib\site-packages\win32com\gen_py\00020813-0000-0000-C
000-000000000046x9x1x0.py
Building definitions from type library...
Generating...
Importing module
```

Now when you call win32com.client.Dispatch on Excel, the object you get back will have attributes that support introspection (from the file that gets created when you run the step above). This is basically creating an early-bound version of the COM object.

This topic is covered in detail in Mark Hammond's "Python Programming on Win32". It's an old book, but still very useful! [http://www.amazon.com/Python-Programming-WIN32-Windows-Programmers/dp/1565926218](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1565926218)

Comment: Not sure if I'm doing it wrong but the introspection seems to involve looking inside `_prop_map_get_` and `_prop_map_put_` on the object rather than the usual Pythonic introspection operators.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, I had some great hope about this. However I cannot seem to find installed application (Inventor and FeatureCAM from Autodesk). Any ideas why they might be missing ? I can access them with win32com.client.Dispatch

Answer (score 2):

The `win32com` module doesn't provide the functions to manipulate an Excel spreadsheet directly. Rather, it provides you a function to acquire an Excel spreadsheet *object*. From this object, you can then manipulate a spreadsheet in an object-oriented fashion:

```
import win32com.client

excel = win32com.client.Dispatch("Excel.Application")
```

The methods and properties available to `excel` can be found in the [Application Object](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-ca/library/bb149132.aspx) documentation, part of the [Excel Object Model Reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-ca/library/bb149081.aspx) at MSDN.

For example, the documentation indicates that an `Application` object has a [`Workbooks` property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-ca/library/bb223063.aspx):

```
workbooks = excel.Workbooks
```

The [`Workbooks` collection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-ca/library/bb210379.aspx) has an [`Open` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-ca/library/bb179167.aspx):

```
workbook = workbooks.Open("C:\\something.xls")
```

You can now manipulate this workbook using the [`Workbook` documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-ca/library/bb245607.aspx)!

As you can see, working with win32com follows the MSDN documentation rather closely. :)

Comment: This looks copied straight off from Python win32 book by Mark Hammond.

Comment: @GTM: Oh? I *wish* I knew that there was book about win32 in Python when I learned this! :) I can assure you, I didn't copy this.