# Auto-completion for win32com and excel

Tags: python, win32com

I am trying to get auto-completion to work for excel functions via win32com. There was a Solution in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2379809/introspection-of-win32com-module-pythoncom-module/41743409#41743409).
I am having a problem with this solution: When I call makepy.py the Excel Object is not there. But in combrowse.py it shows up. Any Idea why?

Update1: Yes, I am sure, that Excel is installed

Comment: Where is your attempted code? And what do you mean auto completion? Do you mean the drag down effect with mouse over range of cells?